# Using VNC with Docker

Tags: docker, vnc

this is my first time using VNC and docker. I want to connect to my docker's GUI.

I have tried to follow a few tutorials online but my VNC viewer cannot connect to the display. I have exposed port 5900 in my dockerfile, and inside docker I have ran 
`Xvbf :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16 & export DISPLAY=:1` and `x11vnc`. It seems to work and I get message saying that the desktop is at port 5900. However I still cannot connect to localhost:5900 in my vnc viewer.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I use to diagnose my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you bind the port when launching the container (`-p`) ?

Comment: Containers don't typically run interactive desktop applications.  If you start running a VNC server, and a GNOME login, and a full desktop environment, you're stepping a little outside the "lightweight packaging around a single process" model, and a full VM running a standard desktop OS might be a better match.

Comment: I have used the -p option. As to the other comment, yes I should probably look to a VM, but I did not write the docker image and are afraid of messing up some system dependencies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I would vote down those "you are using it wrong followed by a completely obvious common place alternative that everyone knows about" type of comments, but I can't. I would assume that people that know about Docker would know about VMs but just want to try running it in Docker for whatever reason. A bit annoying to read  when you are trying to sort something out.